# First C program in Codeblocks

Tags: c

This is my code, written in Codeblocks with GNU compiler. But everytime, when I execute the program crashes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <float.h>

int main()
{
    const float pi=acos(-1.0);
    double radius=0;
    float kreisflaeche;

    printf("Bitte den Radius eingeben.\n");
    scanf ("%d", radius);
    radius=radius*radius;
    kreisflaeche=pi*radius;
    printf("Mit dem eingegebenen Radius, erhält man %d als Kreisflaeche.", kreisflaeche);

    return 0;
}
```

"the exe stopped working" but why?

Comment: regardles the answers, which are correct, in such case, just keep removing lines unitl you find one that fails. Then double check this line and problems will be much easier to solve. Otherwise you'll be downvoted or closed for no effort and broad question

Comment: ...or just, you know, check chapter 1 of your C programming book and see what it says about scanf on integers and scanf on doubles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line `scanf ("%d", radius);` should be `scanf("%lf", &radius);`

Radius is not an `int` so you can't use `%d` and you need to give the address of the variable where the input has to be stored hence using `&`

Here is an excerpt from the man page of `scanf`

> The scanf() family of functions scans input according to format as
>          described below.  This format may contain conversion specifications;
>          the results from such conversions, if any, are stored in the
>          locations pointed to by the pointer arguments that follow format.

You can refer to this [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) for more information on conversion and `scanf()` in general

Answer (score 1):

change

```
scanf ("%d", radius);
```

with

```
scanf ("%lf", &radius);
```

EDIT: added arc676's hint

Comment: `radius` is a double. Shouldn't you use `%f`?

Comment: @Arc676 a double requires `%lf` in `scanf`.